# Github vs. Nuget source code

Tags: spoofing

Suppose I find a library at https://github.com/someorg/somelib. I go onto NuGet and find the "same" library somelib.

Is there any guarantee that what I am getting from NuGet is actually what I see on github -- or a version of it? Would I need to check every time?

Comment: yeah, do a hash on the repo

Comment: Hmmm, my initial question was poorly written. See rewrite above?

Comment: I offer the same answer